# Maximum continuous achievable number

Tags: algorithm, numbers

**The problem**

*Definitions*

- Let's define a natural number `N` as a **writable number** (WN) for number set [image] in `M` numeral system, if it can be written in this numeral system from members of `U` using each member no more than once. More strict definition of 'written': [image] - here `CONCAT` means concatenation.
- Let's define a natural number `N` as a **continuous achievable number** (CAN) for symbol set [image] in `M` numeral system if it is a WN-number for `U` and `M` and also `N-1` is a CAN-number for `U` and `M` (Another definition may be `N` is CAN for `U` and `M` if all `0 .. N` numbers are WN for `U` and `M`). More strict: [image]

*Issue*

Let we have a set of `S` natural numbers: [image] (we are treating zero as a natural number) and natural number `M`, `M>1`. The problem is to find maximum CAN (MCAN) for given `U` and `M`. Given set `U` *may contain duplicates* - but each duplicate could not be used more than once, of cause (i.e. if `U` contains {x, y, y, z} - then each `y` could be used 0 or 1 time, so `y` could be used 0..2 times total). Also `U` expected to be valid in `M`-numeral system (i.e. can not contain symbols `8` or `9` in any member if `M=8`). And, of cause, members of `U` are *numbers*, not *symbols* for `M` (so `11` is valid for `M=10`) - otherwise the problem will be trivial.

**My approach**

I have in mind a simple algorithm now, which is simply checking if current number is CAN via:

1. Check if `0` is WN for given `U` and `M`? Go to 2: We're done, MCAN is null
2. Check if `1` is WN for given `U` and `M`? Go to 3: We're done, MCAN is `0`
3. ...

So, this algorithm is trying to build all this sequence. I doubt this part can be improved, but may be it can? Now, how to check if number is a WN. This is also some kind of 'substitution brute-force'. I have a realization of that for `M=10` (in fact, since we're dealing with strings, any other `M` is not a problem) with PHP function:

```
//$mNumber is our N, $rgNumbers is our U
function isWriteable($mNumber, $rgNumbers)
{
   if(in_array((string)$mNumber, $rgNumbers=array_map('strval', $rgNumbers), true))
   {
      return true;
   }
   for($i=1; $i<=strlen((string)$mNumber); $i++)
   {
      foreach($rgKeys = array_keys(array_filter($rgNumbers, function($sX) use ($mNumber, $i)
      {
         return $sX==substr((string)$mNumber, 0, $i);
      })) as $iKey)
      {
         $rgTemp = $rgNumbers;
         unset($rgTemp[$iKey]);
         if(isWriteable(substr((string)$mNumber, $i), $rgTemp))
         {
            return true;
         }
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

-so we're trying one piece and then check if the rest part could be written with recursion. If it can not be written, we're trying next member of `U`. I think this is a point which can be improved.

**Specifics**

As you see, an algorithm is trying to build all numbers before `N` and check if they are WN. But the only question is - to find MCAN, so, question is:

- May be constructive algorithm is excessive here? And, if yes, what other options could be used?
- Is there more quick way to determine if number is WN for given `U` and `M`? (this point may have no sense if previous point has positive answer and we'll not build and check all numbers before `N`).

*Samples*

```
U = {4, 1, 5, 2, 0}
M = 10
```

then MCAN = 2 (3 couldn't be reached)

```
U = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11}
M = 10
```

then MCAN = 21 (all before could be reached, for `22` there are no two `2` symbols total).

Comment: The second example appears to be incorrect because `11 > 10`

Comment: @JanDvorak why incorrect? `11>10` - yes, but 10 can be combined from `1` and `0` - which are present in `U`

Comment: I mean, why is `11` in `U` if `M=10`?

Comment: @JanDvorak ah, my oversight. Members are `numbers`, not `symbols`. And they are expected to be valid in `M` numeral system (and 11 is valid dec-number). For your point, `F3A` will not be a valid `U` number with `M=10`, but will be valid with `M=16`. Otherwise this problem will be trivial (MCAN will always be not greater than `M` if member of `U` are symbols)

Comment: so, members of `u` are to be treated as base-m digit sequences and writable number is one that can be obtained as a base-m interpretation of the concatenation of base-m representations of some members of `u`? If so, I can't see how MCAN must be not larger than `m`.

Comment: Yes, `N` can be written if it can be a result of concatenation of some subset of `U` members.

Comment: Then it's not true that MCAN must be not larger than m, even if we restrict members of `u` to  be smaller than `m`. Ex. `u={0,0,0,1,1,1}, m=2 => MCAN = 1110_2 = 14`

Comment: @JanDvorak - did not get your point, sorry. Why? MCAN is to be found, we can not say if 'MCAN must be ..' (since it's unknown). We only have some `U` members (possible duplicates) and are trying to get maximum CAN-number for `M` system. For your sample `MCAN = 1110` - yes. What's wrong with that? It's a valid bin number

Comment: "MCAN will always be not greater than M if member of U are symbols" -- how do I interpret this correctly? If I understand "symbols" as "one-digit numbers", then MCAN _can_ be larger than M. If I understand "symbols" as distinct from their values, then MCAN (char[]) is incomparable with M (integer). Its base-M value _can_ be larger than M. Its length can be larger than M as well.

Comment: @JanDvorak hm.. that was a counter-sample of the case, if members of U were symbols (obviously, I am wrong in that). Anyway, we have different case - since members of `U` are not symbols, they are numbers. Thank you for your notice.

Comment: note that concatenation of strings of symbols is equivalent to concatenation of numbers with the restriction that said string of symbols may not start with 0 unless they are 0. Up to type differences, of course.

Comment: @JanDvorak - yes, it is i.e. `10 + 2` = `1`+`0`+`2` - but they're not equal cases since with `10` and `2` we have null as MCAN while with `1`, `0` and `2` it's 2 (suppose `M>2` for both cases). So the problem is more complicated if we have numbers, not symbols.

Comment: wait, what do you get by concatenating `1`, `0` and `1`? If the concatenation is symbolic, variadic or left-associative, you get `101_m` since the leading zero vanishes in `01`. But, if the concatenation is numeric and right-associative, then the value is `11_m`. Frankly, I'd rather drop the concept of numeric concatenation and just say that members of `U` are strings of digits with the leading zero restriction stated explicitly.

Comment: Concatenation is symbolic, so it's `1`, `0`, `1` -> `101` (and I can't figure out how to get `11` from that with any kind of concatenation - may be `0`+`1`+`1` and cast to int? but we have clear order and it's `1` then `0` then `1`)

Comment: 11 can occur if you do this: `1+0+1 = 1+(0+1) = 1+01 = 1+1 = 11`. The point is that the intermediate results are numbers.

Comment: Ah, no. We're dealing only with whole concatenation (intermediate results when doing concatenation do not matter)

Comment: @Jack - what question? And please, don't suggest programmers for such things. It isn't a dumping ground for SO off-topic.

Comment: @Oded I've only put in a single vote; it didn't get migrated, so I think you're just overreacting.

Comment: @Jack - OP cross posted, citing "Stack Overflow" told me to come here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/212078/maximum-ontinuous-achievable-number

Comment: @Oded That's his prerogative ... and I can tell from the friendly welcome why it was a bad idea.

Comment: @Jack - [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Comment: @Oded I fail to see how that relates to myself, I wasn't the one who cross posted, was I?

Comment: @Jack - just in response to "That's his prerogative".

Comment: @Oded That's because it is; unless my supposed role is the mother hen, I do believe you're barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: This question seems like it may be more appropriate for http://cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: In your 2nd bullet point, the definition in words of CAN (which comes first) is different to the definition in the equation. If you want CAN(N) to imply that i must be WN for all 0 <= i <= N, then the sentence fragment that reads "and also N-1 is a WN-number for U and M" should instead read "and also N-1 is a **CAN-number** for U and M". Separately, I don't understand why you introduce V (presumably a subset of U?) in the 1st bullet point's equation.

Comment: @j_random_hacker - yes, yes, exactly so (I mistyped). Fixed, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hash the digit count for digits from `0` to `m-1`. Hash the numbers greater than `m` that are composed of one repeated digit.

MCAN is bound by the smallest `digit` for which all combinations of that digit for a given `digit count` cannot be constructed (e.g., X000,X00X,X0XX,XX0X,XXX0,XXXX), or `(digit count - 1)` in the case of zero (for example, for all combinations of four digits, combinations are needed for only three zeros; for a zero count of zero, MCAN is null). Digit counts are evaluated in ascending order.

Examples:

```
1. MCAN (10, {4, 1, 5, 2, 0})
   3 is the smallest digit for which a digit-count of one cannot be constructed.
   MCAN = 2

2. MCAN (10, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11})
   2 is the smallest digit for which a digit-count of two cannot be constructed.
   MCAN = 21

3. (from Alma Do Mundo's comment below) MCAN (2, {0,0,0,1,1,1})
   1 is the smallest digit for which all combinations for a digit-count of four
   cannot be constructed.
   MCAN = 1110

4. (example from No One in Particular's answer) 
   MCAN (2, {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1111,11111111})
   1 is the smallest digit for which all combinations for a digit-count of five
   cannot be constructed.
   MCAN = 10101
```

Comment: I think error is starting from _Store numbers greater than m as additional counts_. A sample: `MCAN(10, {0,1,2}) = 2` while `MCAN(10, {10, 2}) = null` - but both `0,1,2` and `10, 2` have same symbols

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo in this set `MCAN(10, {10, 2})` , can the numbers 102 and 210 be created?

Comment: MCAN is an abbreviation. From `{10, 2}` only `102` and `210` could be created, yes, so even 0 is not a WN for `{10, 2}` - and so MCAN is null

Comment: what is 'digit count'? Why and what is 'hash'?

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo digit count means how many times the digit appears in the set, for example {1,1,2,3} => 2 counts of 1, 1 count of 2, 1 count of 3. Hash just means to keep a record, so you can look up a digit and see its count, or look up a number and see if it is in the set.

Comment: Then your first point is not correct. `MCAN(2, {0,0,0,1,1,1})=1110` while you're claiming it will be `M-1` (i.e. 1)

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo Actually, my algorithm works perfectly for your last comment. If you continue the algorithm, the digit count for 1 is less than 4, so MCAN is equal to `m^3*digit + m^2*digit + m^1*digit + digit before` = `2^3 + 2^2 + 2^1 + 0` = 14 = 1110 in base 2.

Comment: Sorry, then I can't properly understand your idea. Could you clarify it more formal (may be in standard algorithm language)? With full algorithm cycle

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo I added an extra line to my algorithm. Does that help you see the pattern?

Comment: I see your sample, but it's not clear for me how to act in common case (so I've asked to describe your idea with full cycle (i.e. without 'e t.c.'))

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo I edited some more and hope it will give an idea for the common case.

Comment: Well, now it seems interesting!  (only notice is that on each step we should search not only for number with exact digit count in second hash, but also with greater digits count)

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo como eu disse na resposta, `find the largest digit with the smallest count, where the string "digit" concatenated with itself count + 1 times does not appear in the second hash`

Comment: Trying to implement. Faced a trouble - what if it's `MCAN(10, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1111, 2222, 3333, ..., 9999})` (i.e. no single non-zero numbers at all). I know we should count them somehow, but failing on 1-st step of algorithm

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo ?? `largest digit with smallest count = 1 (count is 0). MCAN = digit before = 0`. No?

Comment: Yes. I should go to sleep :p Thank you.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo I edited to show the algorithm more like pseudo-code. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

The recursion steps I've made are:

1. If the digit string is available in your alphabet, mark it used and return immediately
2. If the digit string is of length 1, return failure
3. Split the string in two and try each part

This is my code:

```
$u = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11];

echo ncan($u), "\n"; // 21

// the functions

function satisfy($n, array $u)
{
        if (!empty($u[$n])) { // step 1
                --$u[$n];
                return $u;
        } elseif (strlen($n) == 1) { // step 2
                return false;
        }

        // step 3
        for ($i = 1; $i < strlen($n); ++$i) {
                $u2 = satisfy(substr($n, 0, $i), $u);
                if ($u2 && satisfy(substr($n, $i), $u2)) {
                        return true;
                }
        }

        return false;
}

function is_can($n, $u)
{
        return satisfy($n, $u) !== false;
}

function ncan($u)
{
        $umap = array_reduce($u, function(&$result, $item) {
                @$result[$item]++;
                return $result;
        }, []);
        $i = -1;

        while (is_can($i + 1, $umap)) {
                ++$i;
        }

        return $i;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your work. As I see, it's also constructive algorithm: check if number is WN, then go to next, while number is WN, right?

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo Yes, I don't think there's another way; and if there is, I would love to know about it :)

Comment: I'm trying actually to understand such way in an answer above (it seems it is non-constructive) - unfortunately, with no success currently.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo and Jack, if you have time, could you please show an example where my algorithm does not work, to help me better understand?

Comment: @groovy I did no implemented it yet - but will try soon

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo When you're doing the recursive step, your prefix must be achievable, but you only test the suffix.

Comment: Jack you mean @groovy 's solution?

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo No, yours! =P ... `if(($iKey = array_search(substr((s ...` <-- that part should do a recursive call.

Comment: @Jack why? This part is trying to find any prefix substring, nothing more. If found, then it do recursive call with the rest part. If it fails, it goes to the next possible prefix. Seems to be working well and tested on many cases

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo You will probably only notice that for numbers above 100, but I haven't looked into that yet.

Comment: @Jack not sure I got that, but I think my implementation provides resolving an issue for any strings (they could be non-numbers)

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo Well, it's for natural numbers, so let's not confuse matters even more :)

Comment: @Jack it seems I got your point. You're confused by function name. it should be `isWriteable` - I agree. For your sample: 101 is _writeable_ but not _achievable_ (fixed that)

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo But `isWriteable(101, [10, 0, 1])` is `false`. I'm arguing that it should be `true`.

Comment: @Jack now I see (my check is not enough)

Comment: @Jack fixed that (added falling back to other options if one failed via `foreach`)

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo Congratulations, you're now the proud owner of messy code; btw, I've forgotten what the question is about anymore :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach:

1) Order the set U with regards to the usual numerical ordering for base M.
2) If there is a symbol between 0 and (M-1) which is missing, then that is the first number which is NOT MCAN.
3) Find the fist symbol which has the least number of entries in the set U.  From this we have an upper bound on the first number which is NOT MCAN.  That number would be {xxxx} N times.  For example, if M = 4 and U = { 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3}, then the number 333 is not MCAN.  This gives us our upper bound.
4) So, if the first element of the set U which has the small number of occurences is x and it has C occurences, then we can clearly represent any number with C digits.  (Since every element has at least C entries).
5) Now we ask if there is any number less than (C+1)x which can't be MCAN?  Well, any (C+1) digit number can have either (C+1) of the same symbol or only at most (C) of the same symbol.  Since x is minimal from step 3, (C+1)y for y < x can be done and (C)a + b can be done for any distinct a, b since they have (C) copies at least.

The above method works for set elements of only 1 symbol.  However, we now see that it becomes more complex if multi-symbol elements are allowed.  Consider the following case:

U = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1111,11111111}

Define c(A,B) = the number of 'A' symbols of 'B' length.

So for our example, c(0,1) = 15, c(0,2) = 0, c(0,3) = 0, c(0,4) = 0,  ...
c(1,1) =  3, c(1,2) = 0, c(1,3) = 0, c(1,4) = 1, c(0,5) = 0, ..., c(1,8) = 1

The maximal 0 string we can't do is 16.  The maximal 1 string we can't do is also 16.
1 = 1
11 = 1+1
111 = 1+1+1
1111 = 1111
11111 = 1+1111
111111 = 1+1+1111
1111111 = 1+1+1+1111
11111111 = 11111111
111111111 = 1+11111111
1111111111 = 1+1+11111111
11111111111 = 1+1+1+11111111
111111111111 = 1111+11111111
1111111111111 = 1+1111+11111111
11111111111111 = 1+1+1111+11111111
111111111111111 = 1+1+1+1111+11111111

But can we make the string 11111101111?  We can't because the last 1 string (1111) needs the only set of 1's with the 4 in a row.  Once we take that, we can't make the first 1 string (111111) because we only have an 8 (which is too big) or 3 1-lengths which are too small.

So for multi-symbols, we need another approach.

We know from sorting and ordering our strings what is the minimum length we can't do for a given symbol.  (In the example above, it would be 16 zeros or 16 ones.)  So this is our upper bound for an answer.

What we have to do now is start a 1 and count up in base M.  For each number we write it in base M and then determine if we can make it from our set U.  We do this by using the same approach used in the coin change problem: dynamic programming.   (See for example http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-7-coin-change/ for the algorithm.)  The only difference is that in our case we only have finite number of each elements, not an infinite supply.

Instead of subtracting the amount we are using like in the coin change problem, we strip the matching symbol off of the front of the string we are trying to match.  (This is the opposite of our addition - concatenation.)

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo and No One in Particular, isn't this the same as my answer?

Comment: groovy, I was typing my answer when yours was posted.  I do believe that they are the same.  I bow to your first answer.

Comment: @NoOneinParticular in that case, I bow to yours as well!

Comment: @groovy -actually, can not check that now. Since my question is not trivial - I'll upvote an answer just because it's author understood my issue :p

Comment: @NoOneinParticular You might need to address the case when `XXX` can be constructed from `X` and `XX`, for example. I cannot seem to find this in your answer.

Comment: In your case example, how will you create the number 29, "11101"?

Comment: @groovy, that is another one which is not doable.  There are many of them.  I was just showing one.  I believe that the dynamic programming part for finding the answer is where most of the work will end up being done.  (Note that you should start at '0' and increment up until you find one which doesn't work.  Using your example, even "10111" doesn't work, which is smaller than your example.)  The more I think about this problem, the more I like it.

Comment: Good point. Your example showed me there's more to be done with my idea, although i think a general formula might be achievable.